# Won't run with CFRelease but zombies with out it

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cgimage

In this code:

```
            url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:t.exportedFullName];

            myImageDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url, (CFStringRef)t.asset.defaultRepresentation.UTI, 1, nil);

            if(!myImageDest) {
                NSLog(@"***Could not create image destination ***");
            }
            inImage = t.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;

            CGImageDestinationAddImage(myImageDest, inImage, (CFDictionaryRef)t.freshMetaData);
            success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(myImageDest);
            if(!success)
                NSLog(@"***Could not create data from image destination ***");

            [url release];
            CGImageRelease(inImage);
            CFRelease(myImageDest);
```

Which runs in a loop loopping through an array of image information (t) if I don't use the CFRelease(myImageDest); I get low memory warnings and the app eventually dies (when running on the device).

If I use it I get:

-[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance

and profiling with Zombies in instruments shows [UIImage dealloc] with a refcnt of -1 and on the line just above it shows CFRelease with a refcnt of 0 in this class above.  The CFRelease shown is the only one in the class.

Can't live with it, can't live without...makin' me crazy...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offending line is:

```
 CGImageRelease(inImage);
```

This shouldn't be needed because `defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage` does not increase the retain count of the returned CGImage.

Also, `[url release]` is not needed for the same reason.

Comment: I took out the [url release]; but with the CGImageRelease() in I still get the message about the call to deallocated instance.  With the CGImageRelease out I get a memory warning and the thing dies.  Any ideas.

Comment: Ok the current version of the code has no [url release] and no cgimagerelease.  The code now passes t.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage directly to CGDestinationAddImage.  Now I don't get the message to deallocted instance but I now I get a segmentation fault 11 with zombies turned off.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:t.exportedFullName];
```

then later

```
[url release];
```

Now that's bad. You don't -alloc/-init, -copy, -mutableCopy nor -retain `url`, so you don't own it. That means, releasing it results in an overrelease of the NSURL instance. So, it's maybe the case that your CGImageRef takes its place in memory, and then...

Remove that release and the CFRelease() function call as well. For the same reason, it's unneccessary.

Comment: I took out the [url release]; but with the CGImageRelease() in I still get the message about the call to deallocated instance.  With the CGImageRelease out I get a memory warning and the thing dies.  Any ideas.

Comment: Ok the current version of the code has no [url release] and no cgimagerelease.  The code now passes t.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage directly to CGDestinationAddImage.  Now I don't get the message to deallocted instance but I now I get a segmentation fault 11 with zombies turned off.

Comment: you're making some other mistakes like this in your code. Watch out for overreleasing other autoreleased object, fix them, then come back.